# Simple clarification about limits

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Ok this is gonna be pretty basic... But I just want to make sure I got this reasoning right. This formula:

[image]

The last transformation after the multipication/division. This is what's going on, right? (excuse the writing)

[image]

Basically it's rearranging the multiplications terms, then separating the fraction in two, and then applying the rule

$$\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{a}{b}*\frac{d}{c}$$

backwards to turn the $\frac{x}{ln(x+1)}$ back into $\frac{ln(x+1)}{x}$, right?

Tangential question, if  the limit of  $\frac{ln(x+1)}{x} = 1$, wouldn't the limit of  $\frac{x}{ln(x+1)} = 1^{-1} = 1$? Letting usk "skip" turning it upside down again?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question actually is but yes if $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$, then $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = 1$

Comment: The question is if what I wrote is right. If to get to the last fraction in the first formula, after the multiplication by $\frac{x}{x}$ I just need to apply the rule for dividing fractions "backwards".

Comment: You got it right more or less, the last step would be to split limit of fraction into a fraction of two limits, which is permittable if the limits exist.